# Desktop Icon in installation package - Windows Install Package

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have successfully packaged up my application to be deployed and installed on a windows workstation. After installing the application on my computer, the desktop icon does not have my app's icon as a graphic. (It has a generic windows icon).

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to make this install package.

Any ideas how I can include a desktop icon in my install package?

Answer (score 4):

Shortcut icons are not set automatically. So make sure you set an icon in "Icon" field from your shortcut's Properties pane.

If an icon is set and it's still not shown, try setting it manually after installation to see if the icon is valid.